# Email validation in js with space in the end

Tags: jquery, email-validation

I am using the following code for email validation, taken from [jQuery By Example](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2011/04/validate-email-address-using-jquery.html):

```js
function validateEmail(sEmail) {
    var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    if (filter.test(sEmail)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}​
```

If I put space after entering the valid email then also its giving me invalid email.
What can I do for that? Tried a lot but not getting the proper result.

Comment: Please include something that replicates your exact problem instead of a link to a blog. People are very seldom inclined to click that.

Comment: what you want exactly space at the end of email or not?

Comment: In the `function where you get input value` do this `var sEmail = $.trim($('#txtEmail').val());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
var sEmail = $('#txtEmail').val();
```

to

```
var sEmail = $.trim($('#txtEmail').val());
```

this should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex instead of that you are using, which is helpful to you to avoid space problem after entered email.

```
/^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)(\s+)?$/
```